# Object doesn't support this property or method, Error 438

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to do some math through VBA, and came across this error which I haven't seen before. Some googling tells me that it has to do with Intelli-Sense options that aren't available for the object being applied to it. But as far as I can tell, it shouldn't be messing up anything here because I didn't use Intelli-Sense in the line the debugger is highlighting. I will post the full code below, any insight is very much appreciated!!

```
    'Declare Variable
    Dim L As Double
    Dim Length As Double
    Dim OrderFTG As Double
    Dim UoM As String
    Dim W As Double
    Dim frm As Access.Form
    Set frm = Forms!Frm_JobTicket
    
    'Set L equal to Length from Tbl_JobTicketMould
    L = DLookup("Length", "Tbl_JobTicketMould", "Access_ID =" & Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Part_Number)
    
    'Convert Length to Feet
    Length = (L \ 12)
    
    'Find Unit of Measure for this part
    UoM = DLookup("Unit_of_Measure", "Tbl_JobTicketUoM", "Access_ID =" & Forms!Frm_JobTicket!Part_Number)
    
    'Mupltiply Length times Quantity to get Order Footage
    OrderFTG = Int((Length * Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket))
    
    'If UoM is PCS then insert that number. Otherwise set equal to Quantity Ordered divided by Length of piece(in FT)
    If UoM = "PCS" Then Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket = Me.Quantity_Ordered Else: Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket = Abs(Int(Me.Quantity_Ordered \ Length))
    
    'Define limits of the loop. Then runs through all Wrap SQ FTG fields and inputs calculation
    For W = 1 To 3
    
       'If UoM is PCS then calculate Order Footage to find Wrap Sqaure Footage. Otherwise take slit size in FT and multiply by Order Quantity and Scrap Rate
    If UoM = "PCS" Then
    frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * OrderFTG) * (frm(RIP_Scrap_Rate + 1)))
    Else: frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * frm(Quantity_Ordered)) * (frm(RIP_Scrap_Rate + 1)))
    End If
    Next W
```

I am also having trouble with this line `OrderFTG = Abs(Int((Length * Me.Txt_Pcs_JobTicket)))`  It keeps coming out to half of the required amount, the data tips for the Abs part of the evaluation will come out to 12,000 and OrderFTG then equals 6,000. I am not sure how that is happening as there is no division whatsoever even happening in that expression.

Thank you!

Comment: Which line is giving the RTE 438?

Comment: @Cyril it is this one, sorry! `frm("Txt_Wrap" & W & "SQFTG_JobTicket") = (((frm("Wrap_Slit" & W) \ 12) * OrderFTG) * (frm(RIP_Scrap_Rate + 1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simpler example demonstrates the problem I think you're dealing with.

I added a text box, *txtScrap_Rate*, to my form, opened it in Form View, and entered the number 27 into the text box.

So then I can retrieve that value with the `frm(<control name>)` approach you're using ... as long as I enclose the control name in quotes.

```vb
set frm = Forms!Form18b
? frm("txtScrap_Rate")
 27 
? frm("txtScrap_Rate") + 1 ' add one to Scrap Rate
 28
```

Without the quotes, Access interprets *txtScrap_Rate* to be an undeclared variable instead of a control name.

```vb
? frm(txtScrap_Rate)
Null
' result is the same as giving it any undeclared variable name, such as this one:
? frm(Bogus)
Null
```

And, without the quotes, if I try to also do the plus one inside the parentheses ...

```vb
? frm(txtScrap_Rate + 1)
```

... I get the same 438 error as you:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

I think you have this issue with `RIP_Scrap_Rate` in two places.  Also I suspect you need to quote the control name in `frm(Quantity_Ordered)`

You would be wise to include `Option Explicit` in your module's Declarations section.  Access will then alert you about anything it thinks is an undeclared variable but you think should be something else.

Comment: It seems like this was the solution, at least to my zero'ing problem! Thank you for that catch.